Typescript inferring method keys doesnt work when the object type is a generic
I am creating a mocking util so I have this method that takes an object and a key on that object that maps to a function, and then a record of possible inputs and outputs:
function mockHook<
    OBJECT extends Record<string, any>,
    METHOD_NAME extends MethodKeys<OBJECT>,
    METHOD extends AnyFunction = OBJECT[METHOD_NAME],
>(
    obj: OBJECT, 
    methodName: METHOD_NAME, 
    mockedConditions: Map<Parameters<METHOD>, Partial<ReturnType<METHOD>>>
)

With these helper types:
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

/**
 * Type to extract only entries on T whose keys are strings and values are methods
 */
type MethodKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? (T[K] extends AnyFunction ? K : never) : never;
}[keyof T];

I have a very common usage where the object has a 'default' key, so I want to create a helper method that will use 'default' as the method name, while enforcing the type.
I tried doing this:
export function mockHookDefault<
    OBJECT extends { default: AnyFunction },
    METHOD extends OBJECT['default'] = OBJECT['default'],
>(obj: OBJECT, mockedConditions: Map<Parameters<METHOD>, Partial<ReturnType<METHOD>>>) {
    return mockHook(obj, 'default', mockedConditions);
}

But I get an error when using the 'default' key:
TS2345: Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type MethodKeys<OBJECT>

What is strange is that if inside the mockHookDefault I do this:
const a: MethodKeys<OBJECT> = 'default';
const b: MethodKeys<{ default: () => {} }> = 'default';

a throws an exception while b doesn't (TS2322: Type string is not assignable to type MethodKeys)
To me it seems like the same type, so why does typescript not allow this and can I fix it without using "as MethodKeys"?
Here is a ts playground demonstrating the issue

MethodKeys<OBJECT> is a complex generic type and thus deferred; TS doesn't know what it will be until OBJECT is instantiated with a specific (non-generic) type. Until then it mostly has no idea what could be assignable to it; expecting otherwise is assuming TS can reason in the abstract about higher-order properties of generic types, but it really can't.  I'd either switch to a specific type, or use a type assertion and move on. See linked q/a above for more information.

For some reason the keys of OBJECT & the MethodKeys of it don't match (found, the conditional typing)
I see the mockHook as focusing on object methods so you focus on them too, making OBJECT more strict and relaxing it on the function parameter:
Playground
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

/**
 * Type to extract only entries on T whose keys are strings and values are methods
 */
type MethodKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? (T[K] extends AnyFunction ? K : never) : never;
}[keyof T];

function mockHook<
    OBJECT extends Record<string, AnyFunction>,
    METHOD_NAME extends keyof OBJECT,
    METHOD extends AnyFunction = OBJECT[METHOD_NAME],
>(obj: OBJECT & Record<string, any>, methodName: METHOD_NAME, mockedConditions: Map<Parameters<METHOD>, Partial<ReturnType<METHOD>>>) {

}

export function mockHookDefault<
    OBJECT extends { default: AnyFunction },
    METHOD extends OBJECT['default'] = OBJECT['default'],
>(obj: OBJECT, mockedConditions: Map<Parameters<METHOD>, Partial<ReturnType<METHOD>>>) {
    return mockHook(obj, 'default', mockedConditions);
}


This solution makes it so that the object has to have ONLY methods as properties, which would block a lot of usages.

For anyone wondering the first associated duplicate has a nice solution by specifying the type:
return mockHook<{default: AnyFunction}, 'default'>(

@Yftach look closer at OBJECT & Record<string, any>  which accepts any objects which could be an elegant solution
